# Triangle Program won't output the results

Tags: java, boolean

Design a class named Triangle that extends GeometricObject
It must contain:

Three double data fields named side1, side2, and side3 with default values 1.0 to denote three sides of the triangle

A no-arg constructor that creates a triangle with specified side1, side2,and side3.

The accessor methods for all three data fields.

A method named getArea() that returns the area if this triangle.

A method named getPerimeter() that returns the perimeter of this triangle.

*A method named toString() that returns a string description for the triangle.

For the formula to compute the area of a triangle, see ProgrammingExercise 2.15( in An introduction to java programming 9th edition) The toString() method is implemented as follows:

return " Triangle: side1 = " + side1 + " side2 = " + side2 + " side3 " + side3;

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter three sides of the triangle, a color, and a boolean value to indicate whether the triangle is filled. The program should create a triangle object with these sides and set the color and filled properties using the input. The program should display the area, perimeter, color and true or false to indicate whether it is filled or not.

**My problem is that it's not outputting the area, perimeter, color and true or false to indicate whether it is filled or not. It just stops after the "Is the Triangle filled? 'True' or 'False'". Somebody help me please?**

Triangle

```
    public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {

private double side1 = 1.0;
private double side2 = 1.0;
private double side3 = 1.0;

Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);    

public Triangle() {
}

public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
    this.side1 = side1;
    this.side2 = side2;
    this.side3 = side3;

}

public double getSide1() {
    return side1;
}

public double getSide2() {
    return side2;
}

public double getSide3() {
    return side3;
}

public void setSide1(double side1) {
    this.side1 = side1;
}

public void setSide2(double side2) {
    this.side2 = side2;
}

public void setSide3(double side3) {
    this.side3 = side2;
}

public double getArea() {
    int p = (int) getPerimeter() / 2;
    return Math.sqrt(p * ((p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3)));
}

public double getPerimeter() {
    return side1 + side2 + side3;
}

public String toString() {
return " Triangle: Side 1 = " + side1 + " Side 2 = " + side2
       + " Side 3 = " + side3;
    }
    }
```

GeometricObject

```
    public class GeometricObject {
private String color = " white ";
private boolean filled;
private java.util.Date dateCreated;


public GeometricObject() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
}

public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();


    this.color = color;
    this.filled = filled; 

}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public boolean isFilled() {
    return filled;
}

public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
    this.filled = filled;
}

public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Created on " + dateCreated + "\n color: " + color + " and filled    ";                 
}   
     }
```

TestTriangle

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TestTriangle  {

private double Side1 = 1.0;
private double Side2 = 1.0;
private double Side3 = 1.0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter three sides of the Triangle");
    double Side1 = input.nextDouble();
    double Side2 = input.nextDouble();
    double Side3 = input.nextDouble();



    System.out.println("Enter the color of the Triangle");
    String color = input.next();


    System.out.println("Is the Triangle filled? 'True' or 'False' ");

    String filled = input.next(); 
}
{
    Triangle triangle = new Triangle(Side1, Side2, Side3);


    System.out.println("The Triangle Sides are \n side 1: " + triangle.getSide1() + "\n Side 2: " + triangle.getSide2() + "\n Side 3: " + triangle.getSide3());

        System.out.println("The Triangle's Area is " + triangle.getArea());

        System.out.println("The Triangle's Perimeter is " + triangle.getPerimeter());

        System.out.println("The Triangle's Color is " + triangle.getColor());
        System.out.println("Is the Triangle filled? " + triangle.isFilled());


        }
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the `}` and `{` between `String filled = input.next(); ` and `Triangle triangle = new Triangle(Side1, Side2, Side3);`...

Comment: I removed the } and { but it didn't do anything.

Comment: also remove `Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);` in Triangle.java class

Comment: WWWHHHAATT holy crap. I would not have detected that one! Thanks so much!